# Unhandled exception at 0x10012c5d (highgui110.dll)

Tags: opencv, unhandled-exception

I had OpenCV lib installed on my machine and all was working fine, until I decided to try the new version of the lib [1.1pre](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=22870&package_id=16937&release_id=633499). Since that moment I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x10012c5d (highgui110.dll) in foo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x719b3856.
```

I've tryied to uninstall and reinstall the lib....same thing happen.
What can I do? How can I fix this problem?

I'm using VS 2005 Express Edition on a Windows Vista OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

- Revert back to the OpenCV lib that worked for you and wait for a non-pre release. Pre-releases are often a bit unstable.
- Get the sourcecode of OpenCV from the sourceforge page. Compile the DLL in debug mode.

  If the crash happends again you'll be able to see the source where it happend. That may or may not give you a hint what went wrong. Maybe you accidently passed a wrong parameter or it's a bug in OpenCV.

  If it's something simple, fix it yourself and submit a patch. Otherwise I suggest that you file a bug-report at the OpenCV project page.

Btw: The bug-tracker is here: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=376677&group_id=22870&func=browse