# show a video from a file in opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv, video-streaming, video-processing

I am trying to open a video (.avi) from a file, read frame by frame and show them in a window. I have looked here in stack overflow and found some interesting codes, but every one of them keeps blowing up my program and I don't know why. I used this code:

```
 int main( int argc, const char** argv ) {

    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    string inputName = "C:\\Users\\Cristina\\Videos\\Capture_me.avi";

    capture = cvCaptureFromAVI( inputName.c_str() );

    if( !capture ) {

        cout << "Capture from AVI didn't work" << endl;

    } else {

         cvNamedWindow( "result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
         cout << "In capture ..." << endl;

         IplImage* currFrame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
         IplImage* prevFrame = cvCloneImage( currFrame );

    while( currFrame = cvQueryFrame( capture ) ) {

          if( !currFrame )

             break;

          cvShowImage( "result", currFrame );
          cvCopy( currFrame , prevFrame );

    }

        waitKey(0);

        cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
        cvReleaseImage( &currFrame );
        cvDestroyWindow( "result" );

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The while loop condition throws: Unhandled exception at 0x0000000066E538C6 (opencv_ffmpeg245_64.dll) in FaceDetection.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000002EF1000.

I also tried the same program but with this loop:

```
while( cvGrabFrame( capture ) ) {

        if( !currFrame )

            break;

        cvShowImage( "result", currFrame );
        cvCopy( currFrame, prevFrame );  
        currFrame = cvRetrieveFrame( capture );

    }
```

This second while loop condition throws the same exception at "currFrame = cvRetrieveFrame( capture );" : Unhandled exception at 0x0000000066E538C6 (opencv_ffmpeg245_64.dll) in FaceDetection.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000003011000.

Can someone please help me understand what is wrong with these codes and how do I fix them? Thanks!!

Comment: In which platform you are running the code? Windows or Linux? And what is the opencv version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a similar question [Unhandled exception at 0x10012c5d (highgui110.dll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820002/unhandled-exception-at-0x10012c5d-highgui110-dll). The main point being that you might be using an unstable version of OpenCV which might have linking problems. Try reverting back to the previous version of OpenCV and see if it works or not. Hope it helps!